# With Lilypad boards, whats the best way to put them into clothing so they can be easiy taken out?

Tags: lilypad, clothing

I want to make a vest that has LED all over it (for the purpose of night time cycling) but i want to be able to easily wash it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use metal snaps.

Answer (score 3):

You could get some industrial velcro and sew it both onto the lilypad and the clothing. Some of the Thinkgeek screenshirts work this way: they have the loop-part on the shirt and the hook part on the hardware.

Answer (score 3):

I have a Lilly Pad, along with several Arduino boards. I've been wanting to do some sewable/wearable projects but just didn't want to ruin the Lilly Pad on a mistake. So after reading Pulsea's instructable: http://www.instructables.com/id/Sewable_Arduino_Interface/
I decided to make a "fabric shield" for a regular Arduino.  It's currently a work in progress, but here are some pics:

[image: http://www.flickr.com/photos/morgellon/4182789768]
[image: http://www.flickr.com/photos/morgellon/4182769288]
[image: http://www.flickr.com/photos/morgellon/4169401395]

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://speedvest.com/

it about a vest with EL wire from coolight.com showing speed of bycicle

good luck